# SQL: Subtracting Larger Row from Smaller Row

Tags: sql

I  am working with Netezza SQL. I have the following table (my_table):

```
  var1 var2 var3 rank var4
1    a    b    c    1   20
2    a    b    c    3   10
3    d    e    f    2   50
4    d    e    f    5   30
```

For each combination of var1, var2, var3 :

- I want to subtract the value of var4 for the smaller rank from the larger rank (i.e. 20-10, 50-30)
- Then, do the same thing but in terms of percentage (e.g. 20 - 10/ 10 * 100%)

The final result would look like this:

```
    var1 var2 var3 var4diff var4percent
---------------------------------------
1    a    b    c      10        50%
2    d    e    f      20        60%
```

I started to write this:

```
WITH ranked AS 
(
    SELECT 
        var1, var2, var3, rank, var4,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1, var2, var3 ORDER BY rank) AS rn
    FROM 
        my_table
)
SELECT 
    a.var1, a.var2, a.var3,
    a.var4 - b.var4 AS var4diff,
    (a.var4 - b.var4) / b.var4 * 100 || '%' AS var4percent
FROM 
    ranked a
```

But I am not sure how to finish this. Can someone please show me what to do?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** My attempt:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT var1, var2, var3, rank, var4,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY var1, var2, var3 ORDER BY rank) AS rn
  FROM my_table
)
SELECT a.var1, a.var2, a.var3,
  a.var4 - b.var4 AS var4diff,
  CASE 
    WHEN b.var4 = 0 THEN '0'
    ELSE CAST(((a.var4 - b.var4) / b.var4 * 100) AS INTEGER) || '%' 
  END AS var4percent
FROM ranked a
JOIN ranked b ON a.var1 = b.var1 AND a.var2 = b.var2 AND a.var3 = b.var3 AND a.rn = b.rn + 1;
```

Comment: "...subtract the value of var4 for the smaller rank from the larger rank..." -- That would be 10-20, not 20-10.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a cross join?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.rank as other_rank, t2.value as other_value, t1.value - t2.value as difference, ((t1.value - t2.value) / t1.value) * 100 as percent
    FROM temp t1
        CROSS JOIN temp t2
    WHERE t1.rank < t2.rank;
```

1. So get all the combinations (using the cross join)
2. We only want the values where the rank is lower than the other rank
3. We then work out the difference and the percentage

Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN/WHERE` is basically a `JOIN/ON`.

Comment: Probably better to give an example?

Comment: Skip the CROSS JOIN ... WHERE, instead go with regular INNER JOIN ... ON.